# basic move_uploaded_file warning from php.net

Tags: php, file-upload

I took this basic upload file script from php.net and it is giving two warning before it move the image to the directory.

> Warning: 
>   move_uploaded_file(public_html/your/inventory_images/penguin.jpg)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home3/ny/public_html/your/anotherformsale.php on line 73
>
> Warning:  move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable
>   to move '/var/tmp/phpnIxYMK' to
>   'public_html/your/inventory_images/penguin.jpg' in
>   /home3/ny/public_html/your/anotherformsale.php on line 73

I am getting this warning after I have tried to upload a image with a basic move_upload script  below.

```
 <?php    
  $uploaddir ='public_html/your/inventory_images/';//<----This is all I
     changed $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

     echo '<pre>'; if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
     $uploadfile)) {
         echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n"; } else {
         echo "Possible file upload attack!\n"; }

     echo 'Here is some more debugging info:'; print_r($_FILES);

     print "</pre>"; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Does the folder `public_html/your/inventory_images` exist as relative path to the .php?

Comment: @PtPazuzu I have the file anotherformsale.php inside your folder and inside your folder I have inventory_images folder where I want to move or save the upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to warning message(`No such file or directory in /home3/ny/public_html/your/anotherformsale.php on line 73`) the path you are using is wrong.

it should be set to

```
$uploaddir ='/home3/ny/public_html/your/inventory_images/';
```

After confirmation of path you should also make sure the destination directory is writable.

Comment: I have the file anotherformsale.php inside your folder and inside your folder I have inventory_images folder where I want to move or save the upload. Still with your answer below I still get the same error. I have fixed to what you said and still the

Comment: @user: do not forgot to add `/` in the front of `home3`. Make sure you have that.

Comment: may I call you bastard? lol  MR Shakti you just made my day. YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS that simple / made the job. One last question how can rename the picture name to this variable $product_id . "jpg" That would be the id of the product.

Comment: @user: Sorry dude but I have to go now. Tip: you have to replace the `basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ` with the `$product_id.".jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

If you read the warning you can see :

- the destination directory does not exist

  or
- you haven't set the correct file permission on it

To solve it check the path, permission, etc...

Comment: it is not fare this is the path I am using home3/nyhungry/public_html/youryardsales/inventory_images/

Comment: all permission are set to 0755

Comment: you're welcome file uploading it's always a fight against path / permission / god ? ... ;)